# Trying to rewrite url in .htaccess resulting in all css/js & admin blocked

Tags: redirect, url-rewrite

After playing with the .htaccess i've hit a brick wall. My site will load from just the domain name but won't load any css or js.

here's my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /magento/

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Magento is located in Httpdocs/magento/

This is my first time editing a .htaccess file

I have base URLS set to http://mystore.com/magento/

I have seo rewrites enabled

Comment: After running firebug i can see that it's calling all the js & css from the root directory.

Comment: why are you not using Magento's default .htaccess file?

Comment: I will try it now, am i right in believing this is the default .htaccess : pastebin.com/gxJpp8Ev? Here is my site if it's any help www.petwholesale.co.uk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Magento's [.htaccess](https://github.com/magento/bugathon_march_2013/blob/master/.htaccess.sample) file
and uncomment (remove `#`)

```
#RewriteBase /magento/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you know where i can find this?

Comment: Click on .htaccess on my reply above :)

Comment: Derp! Didn't see the link! Thanks for that very handy :) I'll put it in the root now and see if it fixes the issue! Thanks again

Comment: Okay i've tried that and now im getting a redirect error.. it doesn't like good... :<

Comment: more details about "redirect error"?

Comment: After continued errors I've decided to backup my theme, and the put a fresh install in the root. I used the default .htaccess FlorinelChis provided and uncommeted the rewriteBase and turned RewriteEninge on. I also needed needed to edited my httpd.conf to AllowOverride ALL. My store is now working perfectly and rewriting the way i would like.